# Inputting Password using service in lock screen

Tags: android, android-service, lockscreen

I want to use the PIN password lock screen (from the Android environment nothing off my own) and just use a service to input the password into the text box when the lock screen is displayed and click the OK.

So to summarize, use a service and through service do the following:
a) Input password.
b) click OK.

both pro-grammatically, possible? I think not but still anyone out there who can make it concrete?

Comment: No it will not defeat the purpose of the PIN/Pass simply because the PIN/Pass has to be correct to actually unlock the device, I'm just wanting to enter input using a service thats it.

Comment: its from my app, I'm developing from 4.3 onwards.

Comment: My App launches a Service that wakes up the screen right now using the keyguardmanager and wakeup and after the wakeup the focus is on the textbox wherein we can enter the number for the PIN and here I want to get my service input the PIN.

Comment: I want to enter the pin "xxxx" using my service started from my app As I already told you that its not bypassing the phone's security as the phone will only get unlocked if the PIN is correct.

Comment: The pin makes its way from a electronic device, is it clear now?

Comment: can it happen like getting the current view in focus in the environment after I wake up and then issue keystrokes?

Comment: I'm  not able to right now get the current view active from the Android environment, how should I go about doing it?